# PHP to SQL add days to date column and post it to new date column

Tags: mysql

I to have this

```
Date 
29/03/2018
+2
Due 
31/03/2018
```

I am using this code , very simple and it works if i add seconds and hours, but if i go above 1 day the due column goes to 00:00:000

```
$sq2= "UPDATE Tickets SET Tickets.due= date(`date`)+20000;
```

( this currently adds 2 hours..)
how do i get past 1 day and have it work correctly?

Comment: I take it that updating your entire database is what you want here? Because that's what you're doing.

Comment: At the moment that is fine, once i get it to add +2 days i will have it limited to the primary key so it will only update 1 row.  can you help me get this to add 2 days? ive tried  increasing the number +20000 but anything that brings it past midnight , it resert to 00:00:0000

Comment: What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: Both `date` and `due` are datetime  displaying dates as 2018-03-29 14:22:02 and 0000-00-00 00:00:00 respectively

Answer (score 0):

If you want a day you can use date_add

```
UPDATE Tickets 
SET Tickets.due= DATE(DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

if you need  minute hour and minute too the don't use date  but

```
UPDATE Tickets 
SET Tickets.due= DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: That didnt work,  the query fails, is this (date, corresponding to my `date` column?

Comment: i have use the same column you have....  added  backtics too and add 1 day

Comment: Okay that added 1 day, excellent that is a step in the right direction- however - it adds 1 day and doesnt retain the hours or minutes in the original date.. can you help me retain that too?